# Java 8 TYPE_USE annotations not behaving if array is annotated inside List or Map

Tags: java, arrays, generics, annotations, java-8

I'm trying to write a simple validation lib with annotations that use the new TYPE_USE target from Java 8. The way to access these things is really complex, and left me with two very messy codes that do exactly the same thing, but are also very coupled to what they actually were meant to do. So I decided to create a simple set of classes to hold this information in a very easy and intuitive way. Basically there is the TypedClass, that is a Class wrapper, but it can be cast to ListClass (Collection or array) or MapClass to access its components (or key / value ) as TypedClass. The most important piece is this helper that is supposed to convert:

```
static TypedClass<?> create(Field f) {
    final TypeResolver typeResolver = new TypeResolver();
    ResolvedType type = typeResolver.resolve(f.getGenericType());
    return create(f.getAnnotations(), type, f.getAnnotatedType());
}

private static TypedClass<?> create(Annotation[] annotations, ResolvedType type, AnnotatedType at) {
    if (type.isArray()) {
        AnnotatedType childAnnotatedType = ((AnnotatedArrayType) at).getAnnotatedGenericComponentType();
        ResolvedType childType = type.getArrayElementType();
        return new ListClass<>(type.getErasedType(), annotations, create(at.getAnnotations(), childType, childAnnotatedType));
    } else if (type.isInstanceOf(Collection.class)) {
        AnnotatedType childAnnotatedType = ((AnnotatedParameterizedType) at).getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
        ResolvedType childType = type.typeParametersFor(Collection.class).get(0);
        return new ListClass<>(type.getErasedType(), annotations, createForGenerics(childType, childAnnotatedType));
    } else if (type.isInstanceOf(Map.class)) {
        AnnotatedType[] att = ((AnnotatedParameterizedType) at).getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments();
        List<ResolvedType> types = type.typeParametersFor(Map.class);
        TypedClass<?> key = createForGenerics(types.get(0), att[0]);
        TypedClass<?> value = createForGenerics(types.get(1), att[1]);
        return new MapClass<>(type.getErasedType(), annotations, key, value);
    }
    return new TypedClass<>(type.getErasedType(), annotations);
}

private static TypedClass<?> createForGenerics(ResolvedType childType, AnnotatedType childAnnotatedType) {
    return create(childAnnotatedType.getAnnotations(), childType, childAnnotatedType);
}
```

Here I am also using ResolvedType from com.fasterxml.classmate, it only serves to bridge between Type and Class in Java, which is also a pain. I don't think it is relevant for the problem, as the structure generated is ok, only the annotations are misplaced.

It seems to be working pretty ok, except when there is an array inside a List or Map. For example:

```
@First("array") List<@First("string") String> @First("list") [] arrayOfListOfString;
```

Works fine (the annotations are matched with the corresponding types). But when I parse

```
List<@First("int[]") Integer @First("int") []> listOfArrayOfInteger;
```

Both the array and the Integer get associated with the @First("int") annotation.

I have debugged my code and I can't find reference to the @First("int[]") annotation anywhere. I'm either missing something very simple or nothing makes sense. The code seems to work in every other scenarios, even the more complex ones. I've been trying to to this for weeks, just recently got to this solution that I thought it would work. Turns out the two coupled methods I had before don't work for this scenario as well (didn't have this specific test). So now I am very stuck.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial call to `create` you pass in the *field* annotations but not the annotations for the `AnnotatedType at`. Therefore, the method `create` is responsible for calling `at.getAnnotations()`. If you look at your implementation you will find out that it will do so only in the array case. In all other cases, your method switches the logic to “the passed in annotation array is the one associated with `at`”.

The problem is that your first example seems to work by accident. You didn’t show the declaration of your `@First` annotation but I suspect that it is allowed for both `@Target`s, `ElementType.FIELD` *and* `ElementType.TYPE_USE`. In this case, a declaration of the form

```
@First("array") List… [] fieldName;
```

is ambiguous and the annotation will be recorded as *both*, a field annotation for `fieldName` and an annotation for the `List…[]` type. So the fact that one annotation array is lost during your recursion is not recognized in the first example because it happens to match the field annotations. But once an annotation is allowed for `TYPE_USE` only but not `FIELD` targets, your code doesn’t even work with your first example.

So you have to decide whether the passed in annotation array shall be the one associated with the `at` parameter or of the surrounding context. It would be easier if both are associated, as in this case you could get rid of that parameter entirely by letting the method retrieve that array rather than the caller.

You should keep in mind:

1. If you want to record all type annotations of a recursive type *and* the field annotations, you will have one more annotation array than type nodes
2. If you want to process `TYPE_USE` annotation primarily, you don’t need to deal with field annotations at all

Here is a simple, straight-forward parsing code finding all annotations:

```
public static void fullType(Field f) {
    AnnotatedType at = f.getAnnotatedType();
    fullType("\t", at);
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
public static void fullType(String header, AnnotatedType at) {
    final boolean arrayType = at instanceof AnnotatedArrayType;
    if(arrayType) {
        fullType(header+"\t",
            ((AnnotatedArrayType)at).getAnnotatedGenericComponentType());
    }
    for(Annotation a: at.getAnnotations())
        System.out.println(header+a);
    if(arrayType) {
        System.out.println(header+"[]");
    }
    else if(at instanceof AnnotatedParameterizedType) {
        AnnotatedParameterizedType apt = (AnnotatedParameterizedType)at;
        System.out.println(header
            +((ParameterizedType)apt.getType()).getRawType().getTypeName());
        System.out.println(header+'<');
        String subHeader=header+"\t";
        for(AnnotatedType typeArg:
            apt.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments())
            fullType(subHeader, typeArg);
        System.out.println(header+'>');
    }
    else if(at instanceof AnnotatedTypeVariable) {
        // when appearing in a Field’s type, it refers to Class’ type variables
        System.out.println(header+at.getType().getTypeName());
    }
    else if(at instanceof AnnotatedWildcardType) {
        System.out.println(header+"?");
        final AnnotatedWildcardType awt = (AnnotatedWildcardType)at;
        AnnotatedType[] bounds=awt.getAnnotatedLowerBounds();
        if(bounds==null || bounds.length==0) {
            bounds=awt.getAnnotatedUpperBounds();
            if(bounds==null || bounds.length==0) return;
            System.out.println(header+"extends");
        }
        else System.out.println(header+"super");
        header+="\t";
        for(AnnotatedType b: bounds) fullType(header, b);
    }
    else {
        assert at.getType().getClass()==Class.class;
        System.out.println(header+at.getType().getTypeName());
    }
}
```

It works flawlessly with your example fields.

Comment: You are more than correct, sir! I though I had to keep the TypeUsage.FIELD, because I added the annotations before the other field modifiers, but if I add they after, I don't need that anymore. Indeed it was the problem that caused me to get the wrong code. Yours is flawless; thanks!

Comment: Actually, I made more tests and your code doesn't seem to work with multidimensional arrays. For instance, parse this `@Ann("float") float @Ann("float[]") [] @Ann("float[][]") [] matrix;` with `fullType` method; it will switch the first and second array's annotations. In my head it should be the way I typed, and not the other way around, but if there is a justification I can just assume that the parsing is right and I have to switch my annotations in the code...

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-architect-annotations-2177655.html section “Applying Type Annotations”

Comment: So it is actually that way. This whole thing is very, very confusing to me. I guess I'll just change my tests then :)

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> ```
> @First("array") List<@First("string") String> @First("list") [] arrayOfListOfString;
> ```
>
> Works fine (the annotations are matched with the corresponding types).

This looks wrong to me.  A type such as

```
@English String @NonEmpty []
```

is read as "non-empty array of English strings".

Now let's consider your example (which I have simplified slightly):

```
@First("array") List @First("list") [] arrayOfList;
```

You have a @First("list") array, where each element is a @First("array") List.  Is that what you want?  It's not what is implied by the names.

I don't know what is wrong with your code in the `listOfArrayOfInteger` case, but you might want to revisit your claim "The code seems to work in every other scenario" given that the one example that you gave seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I understand your point, and I agree with you that that should be the case, but I think it isn't. As it was already pointed out to me at questions/25220215, turns out `@English String @NonEmpty []` is incorrect, and should be `@NonEmpty String @English []`. The idea is: the first annotation applies to the whole field - that is how it's always been. The one in between is related to the pair of brackets - but not the obvious way. You would think the brackets represent the array, but actually they represent the String, because when you index `[i]`, you get a String. Or I'm wrong again :(

Comment: `@English String @NonEmpty []` is correct. If someone recommended `@NonEmpty String @English []`, they are wrong (and they are unfamiliar with the Java 8 specification).

A *method* annotation applies to the entire field (not to the type) and appears at the very beginning of the declaration, along with modifiers such as `public`. By contrast, a *type* annotation appears right before a type and applies to that type. So, in

    @Deprecated @English String @NonEmpty [] words;

The `@Deprecated` applies to the variable words, `@English` applies to `String`, and `@NonEmpty` applies to the array.

Comment: The internal javac representation is a different matter than the specification.  The javac representation of array types is gross, and you will have to do some work to translate between it and the semantics.

Comment: You are right; that’s why it is strongly discouraged to have an annotation that is allowed for `TYPE_USE` and `FIELD`/`METHOD` at the same time. It leads to confusion when the value for such an annotation applies to the element type of an array type and to the entire field/method at the same time. But in this confusing behavior, Java is consistent: the order doesn’t matter, e.g. `@English public @Deprecated String @NonEmpty []` is a correct declaration where `@English` applies to the component type `String` (assuming it’s declared for `TYPE_USE`) and `@Deprecated` applies to the entire field.