# Are annotations on a type parameter accessible in runtime?

Tags: java, annotations, java-8, bean-validation

Java 8 allows things like:

```
public List<@NonNull String> names;
```

But is there a way to access this annotation in runtime or is it available only to compiler plugins?

There's new `Method#getAnnotatedReturnType` that provides access to annotations on the return type, so I was hoping `ParameterizedType` would now have something like `getActualAnnotatedTypeArguments` that would do the same for generic type arguments, but it doesn't exist...

Comment: I don't have time to check it, but one subtype of Type is TypeVariable, which extends AnnotatedElement. Does that have what you need?

Comment: Ah, found it! The correct new type is AnnotatedParameterizedType. Found it by debugging. Thanks a bunch for nudging me in the right direction!

Comment: @yshavit Thanks for pointing this out! It was very inobvious how to get annotated type parameters of a given Class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new API continues the tradition of requiring lots of `instanceof`s and type casts:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class AnnoTest {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
    @interface NonNull {}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
    @interface NonEmpty {}

    List<@NonNull String> list;
    Map<@NonNull Integer, @NonNull @NonEmpty Set<String>> map;
    Object plain;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        for(Field field: AnnoTest.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            AnnotatedType at = field.getAnnotatedType();
            System.out.println(formatType(at)+" "+field.getName());
        }
    }
    static CharSequence formatType(AnnotatedType type) {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for(Annotation a: type.getAnnotations()) sb.append(a).append(' ');
        if(type instanceof AnnotatedParameterizedType) {
            AnnotatedParameterizedType apt=(AnnotatedParameterizedType)type;
            sb.append(((ParameterizedType)type.getType()).getRawType().getTypeName());
            sb.append(Stream.of(apt.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments())
                .map(AnnoTest::formatType).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "<", ">")));
        }
        else sb.append(type.getType().getTypeName());
        return sb;
    }
}
```

See also the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485885/2711488) for an example handling the other scenarios like type variables, wild card types and arrays.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a method `getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments` but in `AnnotatedParameterizedType`, not in `ParameterizedType` where I was looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
 Method method = context.getMethod();
    Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    Object[] parameterValues = context.getParameters();
    for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < annotations[i].length; j++) {
            if (annotations[i][j] instanceof <YourAnnotation>) {
                return (String) parameterValues[j];
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IncompleteAnnotationException(<YourAnnotation>.class, "<YourAnnotation>");
```