# How to get annotations used on generic type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Java's reflection API gives us almost all information about our source code. However, no matter how much I tried, couldn't find a solution for my specific problem.

I have a class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{

    private String someField;

    private int someOtherField;

    private List<@NotNull String> someCollectionField;

}
```

I iterate all fields of this class via reflection, and try to get `@NotNull` annotation used in `List<String>`, but it seems it's impossible using reflection.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454783/10802597

Comment: Nope. This does not solve. Field.isAnnotationPresent() method only works on annotations that are directly present on the field. In my case, @NotNull annotation is present on generic parameter.

Comment: There is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486360/are-annotations-on-a-type-parameter-accessible-in-runtime

Comment: Actually, yes. This is the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are annotations on a type parameter accessible in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486360/are-annotations-on-a-type-parameter-accessible-in-runtime)

Comment: The linked question is mine. I've since forked and extended an excellent reflection library, Gentyref, to work with annotated types, and released the fork under the name GeantyRef. Check it out as it enables very advanced type manipulations.