# How can I get a generic type annotation

Tags: java, reflection, java-annotations

Please tell me, how can I get annotations for a generic type?

Example: I have `public List<@NotNull GuestForm> guests` and I want to get NotNull annotation.

```
public class BookingForm {
    public List<@NotNull GuestForm> guests;

    private List<String> amenities;

    private String propertyType;

    private Unrelated unrelated;

    public BookingForm(List<GuestForm> guests, List<String> amenities, String propertyType, Unrelated unrelated) {
        this.guests = guests;
        this.amenities = amenities;
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
        this.unrelated = unrelated;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want what? can you make it more clear?

Comment: I want to get a list of all annotations declared in a List

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are annotations on a type parameter accessible in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486360/are-annotations-on-a-type-parameter-accessible-in-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class BookingForm {
    public List<@NotNull GuestForm> guests;

    private List<String> amenities;

    private String propertyType;

    private Unrelated unrelated;

    public BookingForm(List<GuestForm> guests, List<String> amenities, String propertyType, Unrelated unrelated) {
        this.guests = guests;
        this.amenities = amenities;
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
        this.unrelated = unrelated;
    }
}
```

```
Object objectClass = requireNonNull(bookingForm); 
var fields = objectClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); // Object fields
var annotations = ((AnnotatedParameterizedType) fields [0].getAnnotatedType()).getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0].getAnnotations(); // Annotations of Generic type in List
```