# Is there something like TypeToken for AnnotatedTypes

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-8

Since there's no type literals in Java, `TypeToken` trick is commonly used instead.
Say, you want to get a `Type` instance representing `List<String>`, you'd do:

```
new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType()
```

Now, I wonder if similar trickery is possible to get an instance of an `AnnotatedType`. For example, to represent `List<@NonNull String>` or even `@NonNull List<@NonNull String>`.

**EDIT:**
[Here's a full `AnnotatedType`-enabled `TypeToken` implementation](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref/blob/master/src/main/java/io/leangen/geantyref/TypeToken.java), provided by [GeAnTyRef](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref).

The gist:

```
public abstract class TypeToken<T> {
    private final AnnotatedType type;

    /**
     * Constructs a type token.
     */
    protected TypeToken() {
        this.type = extractType();
    }

    private TypeToken(AnnotatedType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type.getType();
    }

    public AnnotatedType getAnnotatedType() {
        return type;
    }

    private AnnotatedType extractType() {
        AnnotatedType t = getClass().getAnnotatedSuperclass();
        if (!(t instanceof AnnotatedParameterizedType)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid TypeToken; must specify type parameters");
        }
        AnnotatedParameterizedType pt = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) t;
        if (((ParameterizedType) pt.getType()).getRawType() != TypeToken.class) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid TypeToken; must directly extend TypeToken");
        }
        return pt.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: oh duh - sorry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a type token - or any anonymous subclass with annotated type parameters - with the annotations and [then use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485885/1362755) to extract the annotated types.

Note that this only works for annotations with runtime retention.

Using the `fullType()` method from the linked answer:

```
    List<?> token = new ArrayList<@NonNull String>() {};
    fullType("", token.getClass().getAnnotatedSuperclass());
```

prints

```
java.util.ArrayList
<
    @org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull()
    java.lang.String
>
```

Comment: Ummm... would you mind exemplifying that, as I don't see how is that  possible. E.g new TypeToken<List<@NonNull String>>(){}.getType() would give a ParameterizedType not AnnotatedParameterizedType so how could I extract annotated type parameters from that?

Comment: have you looked at the linked answer and tries the code there?

Comment: Yes I have, and as you can see it's the same way that TypeToken works.

Comment: I now see what you meant. It is indeed similar. Cool, thanks.

Comment: This is getting bizarre. The same line of code that you gave above gives me 1 annotation if executed from a quickly thrown together Main class with a main() method, but 0 annotations if executed from a jUnit test. Digging through the internal implementation led to the method called "filter" that eliminates all annotations not at the same depth(??) as the type being annotated. I have literally no clue what any of that means.

Comment: possibly the difference between a static vs. instance inner anonymous class.

Comment: Turns out it's a bug in JDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952812/why-annotation-on-generic-type-argument-is-not-visible-for-nested-type