# TYPE_USE annotations get lost when type is nested, generic interface

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

It appears that TYPE_USE annotations cannot be accessed through reflection when the annotated type is a nested, generic interface.

Please observe the following example:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class LostAnnotation {
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
  public @interface SomeTypeAnnotation {
  }

  @SomeTypeAnnotation Map<String, String> map;
  @SomeTypeAnnotation Entry<String, String> entry;

  public static @SomeTypeAnnotation Entry<String, String> someMethod(
      @SomeTypeAnnotation Map<String, String> map,
      @SomeTypeAnnotation Entry<String, String> entry) {
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<LostAnnotation> clazz = LostAnnotation.class;
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("someMethod", Map.class, Entry.class);
    AnnotatedType[] types = method.getAnnotatedParameterTypes();

    print("map field", clazz.getDeclaredField("map").getAnnotatedType());
    print("map parameter", types[0]);

    print("entry field", clazz.getDeclaredField("entry").getAnnotatedType());
    print("entry parameter", types[1]);
    print("entry return type", method.getAnnotatedReturnType());
  }

  static void print(String title, AnnotatedType type) {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", title, Arrays.asList(type.getAnnotations()));
  }
}
```

The **expected output** of the above code is

```
map field: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
map parameter: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
entry field: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
entry parameter: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
entry return type: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
```

However, the **actual output** of the above code is

```
map field: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
map parameter: [@LostAnnotation$SomeTypeAnnotation()]
entry field: []
entry parameter: []
entry return type: []
```

The annotation is correctly retrieved from every usage of the `Map` interface. However, on every usage of the `Entry` interface, be it field, return type or parameter, the annotation is lost. The only explanation that I have for this is that the `Entry` interface is *nested inside* the `Map` interface.

I ran the above example on the newest oracle JDK (8u121) on win64. Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug?

*My Annotation is nested for readability. Making it a top-level interface doesn't change anything.*

Comment: I tested and played around with your code and can't find any error in your code from your side. So I agree with kriegaex, this seams to be a bug in the jvm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been already spotted in [SO: Why annotation on generic type argument is not visible for nested type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952812/why-annotation-on-generic-type-argument-is-not-visible-for-nested-type)

Answer is bug has been submitted but in lower priority as those cases do not appear frequently.

Still, you can use [ByteBuddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) to parse the bytecode and retrieve the annotated type.

[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) works too, from my experience, and I suspect any bytecode parser would work around this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I count as a credible source (definitely not an official one), but IMO this is a bug or at least a shortcoming (not fully implemented) in the JDK.

You are not doing anything wrong - or we are both wrong, which is still a possibility.

As Bertrand Russell said:

> The fact that an opinion has been widely held is no evidence whatever that it is not utterly absurd.

;-)