# How to get TYPE_USE annotations on a generic bound

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8, annotations

I have this case:

```
public class SomeClass<T> {
    public <@A1 S extends @A2 T> @A3 S myMethod() { ...}
}
```

and I'm trying to get the `@A2` annotation on the bound `T`.
This is what I'm seeing, assuming `myMethod` is `SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod")`. Type casts removed for readability.

- `myMethod.getGenericReturnType().getAnnotations()` returns `@A1` (as expected, I guess)
- `myMethod.getGenericReturnType().getBounds()[0].getAnnotations()` returns *nothing* (?? shoudn't it be `@A2` ??)
- `myMethod.getAnnotatedReturnType().getAnnotations()` returns `@A3` (as expected, I guess)
- `myMethod.getAnnotatedReturnType().getAnnotatedBounds()[0].getAnnotations()` returns *nothing* (as excepted, I guess)

It seems like `@A2` got lost... and that doesn't sound sensible. Am I doing something wrong or is this indeed some bizarre behavior?

UPDATE:
It is indeed a JDK bug, which I reported and it got accepted as [JDK-8191466](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8191466)

Comment: never actually needed to do this... but a very good question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All type annotations can be retrieved through the `AnnotatedType` hierarchy, except for the `TypeVariable`, whose annotations can be retrieve through `AnnotatedTypeVariable.getType()` which will be an instance of `TypeVariable` which extends `AnnotatedElement` now and happens to be identical with the object returned by `Method.getGenericReturnType()`.

So you can retrieve all information, e.g.

```
AnnotatedType art = myMethod.getAnnotatedReturnType();
System.out.print(
    Arrays.toString(art.getAnnotations())+" "+art.getType().getTypeName()+" -> ");
final boolean typeVariable = art instanceof AnnotatedTypeVariable;
if (typeVariable) System.out.print('<');
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(((AnnotatedElement)art.getType()).getAnnotations()) + " ");
System.out.print(art.getType().getTypeName());
if (typeVariable) {
    AnnotatedTypeVariable atv = (AnnotatedTypeVariable)art;
    AnnotatedType[] annotatedBounds = atv.getAnnotatedBounds();
    if (annotatedBounds.length > 0) {
        System.out.print(" extends ");
        for (AnnotatedType aBound: annotatedBounds) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(aBound.getAnnotations()) + " ");
            System.out.print(aBound.getType().getTypeName() + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(">");
}
```

will print

```
[@A3()] S -> <[@A1()] S extends [@A2()] T, >
```

When your invocation of `((AnnotatedTypeVariable)myMethod.getAnnotatedReturnType()) .getAnnotatedBounds()[0].getAnnotations()` does not provide `@A2`, you should recheck that `A2` truly has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`.

Of course, that’s the “simplified” version handling only your specific method.

To handle all possible cases, you will need much more `instanceof`s, dealing with these disjunct type hierarchies of `Type` and `AnnotatedType`, especially when processing annotated parameterized types and annotated generic array types.

As said, `TypeVariable` is different, as it extends `AnnotatedElement` and also has the `getAnnotatedBounds()` method. So in this specific case, an alternative way to process the method is

```
List<TypeVariable<?>> typeParameters = Arrays.asList(myMethod.getTypeParameters());

for (TypeVariable<?> tv: typeParameters) {
    System.out.print("< "+Arrays.toString(tv.getAnnotations())+" "+tv.getName());
    AnnotatedType[] annotatedBounds = tv.getAnnotatedBounds();
    if (annotatedBounds.length > 0) {
        System.out.print(" extends ");
        for (AnnotatedType aBound: annotatedBounds) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(aBound.getAnnotations()) + " ");
            System.out.print(aBound.getType().getTypeName() + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("> ");
}

AnnotatedType art = myMethod.getAnnotatedReturnType();
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(art.getAnnotations()) + " ");
int ix = typeParameters.indexOf(art.getType());
if (ix >= 0) System.out.print("[ref to type parameter #" + ix + "] ");
System.out.println(art.getType().getTypeName());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this (upvoted)! But... it made me realize what makes `@A2` _disappear_ in my case is the fact `T` in my example come from the class definition (I modified the code above to show that `SomeClass<T>` contains `myMethod`). Now, I understand that changes the situation, but it must be possible to still retrieve the annotation in some way... yet there doesn't seem to be a way. Your code doesn't recover it, just like mine didn't.

Comment: Indeed even recursively applying the `AnnotatedTypeVariable` processing doesn’t help in that case. The annotation seems to be missing.

Comment: Its [not the first bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952812/why-annotation-on-generic-type-argument-is-not-visible-for-nested-type) in JDK8's annotation processing. I wonder if JDK9 behaves differently.

Comment: At least, I could verify that the information is present in the compiled class file. Java 9 does not show any difference.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the extra info! I'll accept the answer as I'm sure this is as far as one can go.